# Using Puppet, is it possible to define which plugins gets sync with a particular client?

Tags: puppet

I have a `plugin` that gets pushed to all clients. However, I have one that's specific to a particular module, hence I don't want it synced with all my clients.

My generic plugin is stored in `/etc/puppet/modules/custom/lib/facter` but I have a plugin stored inside a module that seems to be pushed to all clients regardless if the host inherits the class or not.

Location of module:
`/etc/puppet/modules/apache/lib/facter/SAMPLE_PLUGIN.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Limited which nodes receive the plugins isn't really possible unless you hack up the rack config.ru file. There is no real API for hacking how Rack interacts with the webserver, but if you really need this feature see some examples here: http://rcrowley.org/talks/puppet-camp-2010/#72

However, you should really look into
[Confine in Facter](http://downloads.puppetlabs.com/facter/apidocs/classes/Facter/Util/Confine.html) instead.

It's designed to only run facter discovery under special conditions.